# An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'bitnami_myapp'

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I haven't defined a database named `bitnami_myapp` anywhere?

My `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '2'

services:
 myapp:
  image: 'docker.io/bitnami/symfony:1-debian-10'
  ports:
   - '8000:8000'
  volumes:
   - '.:/app'
  depends_on:
   - mariadb
 mariadb:
  image: 'docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3-debian-10'
  environment:
   - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
   - MARIADB_USER=andy
   - MARIADB_DATABASE=symfony_red
   - MARIADB_PASSWORD=password
  ports:
   - "4307:3306"
```

My `.env` file:-

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://andy:password@127.0.0.1:4307/symfony_red?serverVersion=5.7
```

These are newly installed symfony/bitnami images for: `mariadb` and `Symfony` service containers.

```
$ docker-compose up
```

Steps to recreate:

login to the symfony container

```
root@b8790e2f3021:/app/myapp#
```

and run command:

```
$ bin/console doctrine:migrations:status
```

receive:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'bitnami_myapp'
```

How do I get symfony/doctrine to use my database defined in `docker-compose.yml` rather than looking for: `bitnami_myapp` ?

Comment: Does your directory contain some files like `.env.local` or `.env.dev` or `.env.dev.local` ?

Comment: Yes, I recall seeing `.env.local`

Comment: Look at its content, I guess there is some information that override your settings.

Comment: It was that, your right. I thought the .env.local was ignored - my novice exp with symfony. thanks.

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer and add a link to documentation explaining the priorities of the files to know which one are read and which one override the others.

Comment: If there are no .env files containing bitnami_myapp or anything, they may be variables set in the docker image build process, check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75217051/laravel-wont-connect-to-database-server-that-set-in-env-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directory contains some files like `.env.local` or `.env.dev` or `.env.dev.local`.

You should find them, verify and edit their contents.

Here is the [chapter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#overriding-environment-values-via-env-local) of the documentation their priorities.