# Laravel won't connect to database server that set in .env file

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I started a new Laravel 9.x + JsonApi project on docker-compose with 2 containters, 'web' and 'mysql'. Artisan migrations, seeding and db:show works fine. But when I'm trying to load a page from browser or Postman, it returns DB error

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for **mariadb** failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

select * from `redirects` where `redirects`.`id` = 1 limit 1 `

The weird part is that my DB host is **mysql** and 'mariadb' string is never mentioned in my code (except some vendor files), nor in docker files, nor in .env file. I also checked container environment variables - nothing there.

Artisan scripts work fine.

Here are my settings, if it helps. Mariadb was never mentioned, it was mysql from the very beginning.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    volumes: 
      - mysql_db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=url_shortener
  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.web.dev
      context: .
    #image: php:alpine
    volumes:
      - "./:/app"
      - "/app/src/vendor"
      - web_root_home:/root
    working_dir: /app/src/
    command: "php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=7999"
    ports:
      - 8000:7999
    depends_on:
      - mysql
volumes:
  mysql_db:
  web_root_home:
```

Dockerfile.web.dev

```
#FROM php
FROM bitnami/laravel
WORKDIR /app/src/
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y git build-essential vim mc mlocate
RUN pecl install xdebug
COPY ./src /app/src
COPY ./src/composer.json ./
COPY ./src/.env ./
RUN composer install
RUN php artisan key:generate

CMD ["php", "artisan", "serve", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]
```

.env (DB part)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=url_shortener
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=***
```

app/config/database.php wasn't changed

artisan db:show

```
root@a3c873713ee1:/app/src# php artisan db:show

  MySQL 8 ...................................................................
  Database .................................................... url_shortener
  Host ................................................................ mysql
  Port ................................................................. 3306
  Username ............................................................. root
  URL .......................................................................
  Open Connections ........................................................ 3
  Tables .................................................................. 6
  Total Size ........................................................ 0.09MiB

  Table .......................................................... Size (MiB)
  redirects ............................................................ 0.02
  failed_jobs .......................................................... 0.02
  migrations ........................................................... 0.02
  personal_access_tokens ............................................... 0.02
  password_resets ...................................................... 0.02
  users ................................................................ 0.02
```

migrations and seeding works fine, I can connect to mysql from the host laptop. All seeds data are there

I tried to clear config cache, didn't help

```
root@a3c873713ee1:/app/src# php artisan config:clear

   INFO  Configuration cache cleared successfully.
```

I also reloaded containers, no luck as well

Stack trace isn't useful [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDkVP.png)

I'm out of ideas what to try and where it takes this mariadb host at all.

Comment: In your error trace, on the left, you see 48 stacks collapsed... expand that, and see if there is any custom code (non core code) that may be changing something, or using a custom config that is not the DB config you have put (like a package config), you have to literally go from the error, slowly out following the trace, until you find who is passing a maybe wrong value

Comment: I tried that that but I didn't find anything meaningful there. It's just db query all the way down.
Also, I believe config is being loaded in different function. Installing xdebug to check it...

Comment: You don't have multiple dockers running at all do you? I'd try sail down then sail up -d just to make sure the latest docker is running

Comment: I don't have multiple docker running. Also, I didn't use sail (it didn't work for me so I set up containers manually). Views that don't use db work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem by defining the `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:PASSWORD@mysql/url_shortener` in my `.env` file. I still have no idea where it got mariaDB host from.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was a problem with bitnami's laravel docker image. At [build time they set certain environment variables](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/laravel/9/debian-11/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel-env.sh#L65) which are then read (where, I wasn't able to find, maybe it interacts with a bug in another library).

Solution for me was setting DB_HOST, DB_CONNECTION, DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD to my "default" connection in docker-compose.yml